# Javascript Object´s Attribute forgets value

Tags: javascript

I´m not very experienced with JavaScript.

I defined an Object with an attribute.
A method of the object makes a jQuery post with another method of the object as callback.
In this second method the attribute has forgotten its value, alert prints 'undefined'

```
var myObj=
{ attr1 : 'val1',

  method1 : function()
    { $.post("__AX_getContent?edit=true").done(this.method2);
      alert(this.attr1);
    },

    method2: function(data)
    { alert(this.attr1);
    }
}

$(myObj.method1());
```

what am I doing wrong to have the attributes value in method2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `this` in the second method is a `XHR` object send by AJAX.

Try using the `.bind` function prototype.

```
$.post("__AX_getContent?edit=true").done(this.method2.bind(this));
```